# Append svg icon always right behind the text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

So I work with D3.js and I have a radar chart with data which are represented by text positioned within a circle.

Texts have always different length and I would like to directly after each of these texts append an icon in this order: chart, text label, trash can.

I already tried to calculate length within an attribute where the text is rendered, which gives me length of each label correctly, but then I did not manage to append icon:

```
.attr("lenght", function() {
          var datalong = this.getComputedTextLength();
       })
```

Then I as well tried to append icon separately which works, but I don't know how to then get the length:

```
axis.append("svg:image")
        .attr("xlink:href","http://svgur.com/i/121.svg")
        .attr("y",-7)
        .attr("opacity",1)
        .attr("transform", function(d, i,e) {
          var angleI = angleSlice * i * 180 / Math.PI - 90; 
          var distance = radius * options.trash.trashFactor; 
          var flip = angleI > 90 ? 180 : 0; 
          return "rotate(" + angleI + ") translate(" + distance + ")" + "rotate(" + flip + ")"
        });
```

Then I tried to append icon in method where I write data (text), but the icon did not show up. I tried to wrap them into groups and position them next to each other, but also without succeed.

I have a JSFiddle with somewhat closest option I was able to get. I hope it is possible to understand what I am trying to do, if not please refer to fiddle and where you can easily understand what I am trying to achieve.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fsb47ndf/5/

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Gerardo, always after in this order: chart, text labels, trash can.

Comment: OK, in the question you say "behind", so I was confused...

Comment: Thanks for input, I edited question for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the length of the texts with this cumbersome math:

```
var textLength = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text").node().getComputedTextLength();
```

Basicaly, this is what the code does:

- `d3.select(this.parentNode)`: It selects the parent of the icon, then...
- `select("text").node()`: It selects the text which is child of that parent, and finally...
- `getComputedTextLength()`: It gets the length of that text.

Then, you use it to set the distance of the icons:

```
    var distance = angleI > 90 ? radius + textLength + 40 : radius + textLength + 30;
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0L4xzmfo/

And here the same code in the snippet:

```js
 data = [{
   name: 'DATA11111',
   value: 22,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA2',
   value: 50,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA33333333',
   value: 0,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA444444',
   value: 24,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA55',
   value: 22,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA6666',
   value: 30,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA7',
   value: 20,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA8',
   value: 41,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA9',
   value: 31,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA10',
   value: 30,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA1121213213',
   value: 30,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA12',
   value: 30,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA1123123212313',
   value: 30,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA14',
   value: 30,
 }, ];



 var options = {

   width: 600,
   height: 600,

   margins: {
     top: 100,
     right: 100,
     bottom: 100,
     left: 100
   },

   circles: {
     levels: 6,
     maxValue: 100,
     labelFactor: 1.15,
     dataFactor: 1.09,
     opacity: 0.2,
   },

   trash: {
     trashFactor: 1.32
   }

 };


 var allAxis = (data.map(function(i, j) {
     return i.name
   })),
   total = allAxis.length,
   radius = Math.min(options.width / 2, options.height / 2),
   angleSlice = Math.PI * 2 / total,
   Format = d3.format('');

 var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain([0, options.circles.maxValue])
   .range([50, radius]);

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", options.width + options.margins.left + options.margins.right)
   .attr("height", options.height + options.margins.top + options.margins.bottom);

 var g = svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + (options.width / 2 + options.margins.left) + "," + (options.height / 2 + options.margins.top) + ")");

 var axisGrid = g.append("g")
   .attr("class", "axisWraper");

 var axis = axisGrid.selectAll(".axis")
   .data(allAxis)
   .enter()
   .append("g")
   .attr("class", "axis")

 //append them lines
 axis.append("line")
   .attr("x1", 0)
   .attr("y1", 0)
   .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
     var tempX2 = radius * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
     return tempX2;
   })
   .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
     var tempY = radius * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
     return tempY;
   })
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("stroke", "black")
   .attr("fill", "none");

 //Draw background circles
 axisGrid.selectAll(".levels")
   .data([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("class", "gridCircle")
   .attr("r", function(d, i) {
     return parseInt(radius / options.circles.levels * d, 10);
   })
   .attr("stroke", "black")
   .attr("fill-opacity", options.circles.opacity);

 //Write data
 axis.append("text")
   .attr("class", "labels")
   .attr("font-size", "12px")
   .attr("font-family", "Montserrat")
   .attr("text-anchor", function(d, i) {
     var angleI = angleSlice * i * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
     return angleI > 90 ? "end" : "start"
   })
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .attr("fill", "black")
   .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
     var angleI = angleSlice * i * 180 / Math.PI - 90; // the angle to rotate the label
     var distance = radius * options.circles.dataFactor; // the distance from the center
     var flip = angleI > 90 ? 180 : 0; // 180 if label needs to be flipped
     return "rotate(" + angleI + ") translate(" + distance + ")" + "rotate(" + flip + ")"
   })
   .text(function(d) {
     return d;
   });


 axis.append("svg:image")
   .attr("xlink:href", "http://svgur.com/i/121.svg")
   .attr("class", "trash")
   .attr("y", -7)
   .attr("text-anchor", "end")
   .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
     var textLength = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text").node().getComputedTextLength();
     var angleI = angleSlice * i * 180 / Math.PI - 90; // the angle to rotate the label
     var distance = angleI > 90 ? radius + textLength + 40 : radius + textLength + 30; // the distance from the center
     var flip = angleI > 90 ? 180 : 0; // 180 if label needs to be flipped
     return "rotate(" + angleI + ") translate(" + distance + ")" + "rotate(" + flip + ")"
   });
```

```css
.trash {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

PS: I'm using a magic number because I didn't look at the code to find the exact padding of the text. Please change that magic number accordingly.

Comment: It's weird, it doesn't work with Firefox, but it does with Chrome

Comment: Looks like firefox needs `height` and `width` for the image

Comment: It seems to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another idea, to use FontAwesome font and icons. This way you avoid the appending of svg:image.

```
.html(function (d, i) {
    var angleI = angleSlice * i * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
    if (angleI > 90) {
        return '&#xf014; ' + d;
    } else {
        return d + ' &#xf014;'
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fsb47ndf/25/

&#xf014 is FA unicode for trash icon (http://fontawesome.io/icon/trash-o/). Rotate the icon the same way you rotate text.